# How to fix jQuery multiple else if statements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run this function but it doesn't reach the first else if when I reach the specified screen size, it will continue to use the first if.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  function removeClass() {
    $('#cookbook_add').removeClass('st-remove-label');
    $('#email_page').removeClass('st-remove-label');
  }

  function addClass() {
    $('#cookbook_add').addClass('st-remove-label');
    $('#email_page').addClass('st-remove-label');
  }

  function addRemoveLabel() {
    lastWidth = $(window).width();
    if (lastWidth < 1150) {
      console.log('1150');
      addClass();
    } else if (lastWidth < 975) {
      console.log('975');
      removeClass();
    } else if (lastWidth < 680) {
      console.log('680');
      addClass();
    } else {
      removeClass();
    }
  }
  addRemoveLabel();
});
```

I expect the console logs to fire when the screen is that size, but it doesn't.

Comment: sidenote: you can probably do this with a CSS @media rule targetting those widths.

Comment: Your first `if` is be valid for all width's smaller then 1150 so the execution will always stop there.

Comment: @Shilly I tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can combine selectors `$('#cookbook_add, #email_page').removeClass('st-remove-label')`... or use one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a range greater than and lower than for each of the if statements

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  function removeClass() {
    $('#cookbook_add').removeClass('st-remove-label');
    $('#email_page').removeClass('st-remove-label');
  }

  function addClass() {
    $('#cookbook_add').addClass('st-remove-label');
    $('#email_page').addClass('st-remove-label');
  }

  function addRemoveLabel() {
    lastWidth = $(window).width();
    if (lastWidth < 1150 && lastWidth > 975) {
      console.log('1150');
      addClass();
    } else if (lastWidth < 975 && lastWidth > 680) {
      console.log('975');
      removeClass();
    } else if (lastWidth < 680) {
      console.log('680');
      addClass();
    } else {
      removeClass();
    }
  }
  addRemoveLabel();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/on0pet6g/

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for showing me how it should be done.

Comment: @MaxLoyd happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first if will be reached with any number < 1150... so 975 is < than 1150, 680 is < than 1150.

The best way is to compare the lowest values first like that:

```
        if (lastWidth < 680) {
            console.log('680');
            addClass();
        }
        else if (lastWidth < 975) {
            console.log('975');
            removeClass();
        }
        else if (lastWidth < 1150) {
            console.log('1150');
            addClass();
        }
        else {
            removeClass();
        }
```

Just change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to

```
function addRemoveLabel() {
lastWidth = $(window).width();
if (lastWidth <= 1150 && lastWidth > 975) {
  console.log('1150');
  addClass();
} else if (lastWidth <= 975 &&lastWidth > 680) {
  console.log('975');
  removeClass();
} else if (lastWidth <= 680) {
  console.log('680');
  addClass();
} else {
  removeClass();
}
```

}